# Simple Inequality to Prove

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given $a,b,c,d\mathbb\in{R}$ and $a>b$ and $d>c$ how do I prove that $a-c>b-d$?

I started the proof like this:
given: $a>b$ I can add to both sides of the ineqality -c therefore I get:
$a-c > b-c$

How can I show now that $a-c>b-d$?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: if $d > c$, then $-c > -d$ and therefore $a-c>b-c>b-d$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $d > c$, then $-c > -d$ and therefore $a-c>b-c>b-d$

Comment: Sweet, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You could verify that $(a-c) - (b-d)>0$. Towards this end, use the fact that both $a-b>0$ and $d-c>0$.